# How to write $ u(x,t) $ in Forward Time Central Space scheme?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, finite-differences

If I want to apply the FTCS scheme to the following equation:

$$
\frac{\partial u(x, t)}{\partial t} = f(x)u(x, t)
+A\frac{\partial u(x, t)}{\partial x}+B\frac{\partial^{2}u(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}}
$$

The first term in the right hand side is approximated (written as) by:

$$ a) \qquad f(x) u(x, t) = f(i, j)u(i, j)\ $$

Or,

$$
b) \qquad f(x)u(x, t) = \left(\frac{f(j-1)+f(j+1)}{2}\right)\kern-9mu
\left(\frac{u(i, j-1)+u(i, j+1)}{2}\right)
$$

What is the reason for choosing either or?

Thank you so much!

Comment: a) is correct. In FDM we write discretized equation at the mesh point $(x_i,t_j)$ and since there is no derivative in the term $f(x)u(x,t)$, hence no approximation is needed for it.

Comment: OK thank you so much!